# No builds available for individual testers in testFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, build-version

I have uploaded the first build of my react-native app to AppStore connect testFlight.

The invitations to `App Store Connect Users` are sent and they have received the email. But the individual testers that I add with their email address, not receiving. any email and in the console I see the `No build is available`.

What is going wrong here. *I am totally new to the app store connect environment*

[image]

Comment: Has the build been [reviewed and approved by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) already?

Comment: @fsb How should I make sure of that? the fact that the build is there and `App Store Connect Users` can use it doesn't mean it is approved?

Comment: No.  Your App Store Connect users can use the app without Apple's beta review process.  To make your beta builds available to external users, your beta build may require review.  I'm guessing your build hasn't received approval yet. I recommend you read Apple's Test Flight documentation.

Comment: Thanks fsb, that worked for me. Amazing how it takes 5 mins to get users testing on Android but for iOS I have to spent 2 hours trying to find out why it's not available.

Comment: @Devilscomrade We developed for various platforms (mobile and desktop) using IDE's from different vendors.    The entire Apple developer ecosystem is a painful mess.  We regularly spend days trying to explain mysterious roadblocks and vague messages.  This is just another one of the same.  Get used to it.